# A better Dispose method ( through ComponentModel.IContainer ?? )

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I have this Dispose method I want to change. (Yeah I should check every object for null, I know)

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if( monthLineBrush != null)
                monthLineBrush.Dispose();
            monthHeaderLineBrush.Dispose();
            shadowBrush.Dispose();
            monthHeaderLineBrushDark.Dispose();
            monthFontBrush.Dispose();
            weekendBgBrush.Dispose();
            whiteBrush.Dispose();
            dayFontBrush.Dispose();
            chartBrush.Dispose();
            chartWarningBrush.Dispose();
            barBrush.Dispose();
            monthLinePen.Dispose();
            monthHeaderLinePen.Dispose();
            monthHeaderLinePenDark.Dispose();
            warningLinePen.Dispose();
            monthFont.Dispose();
            yearFont.Dispose();
            weekLinePen.Dispose();
            dayLinePen.Dispose();
            tooltip.Dispose();
            toolTipLabel.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

VS uses a System.ComponentModel.IContainer object named components , and only disposes this components object. Yet I can't find any code where the different objects are added to the components objedct ??

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

How does this work ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The code to add each object that is created to the `components` container is automatically generated and added to the `*.Designer.cs` file associated with each form by the designer.**

For example, the `Form1.Designer.cs` file might look something like this in a brand new, empty project once you've added a `ToolTip` control to the form:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 264);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

There are two relevant lines of code in that whole mess, the two that appear at the very top:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
```

The first line creates a [`System.ComponentModel.Container`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.container.aspx) object called `components`, to which all of the components that implement `IDisposable` will be added when they are created.

The second line creates a `ToolTip` object (in response to one being drug to the form's surface during design time), and uses a [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5d6h5z2z.aspx) that accepts a parameter of type `IContainer`.

Extending this same song and dance to the other components that are added to your form allows them all to be disposed at one go with the [`Dispose` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b22tcd4.aspx) provided by the `components` container.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I understand now. However, I can't add brushes, pens or fonts to the container ?? It would be pretty useless then ...

Comment: i dont think so, objects you want to add to the container need to implement IComponent ... you'll get a "the best overloaded match for Add( Icomponent ) has some invalid arguments " error when adding brushes or pens ...

Comment: @Run CMD: You're right; I answered that way too quickly. No, you can't add those objects. But there's nothing stopping you from creating your own custom `Collection<IDisposable>` and providing a public `Dispose` method that iterates through all of the objects in the collection and calls their `Dispose` methods. I'd be willing to bet (although not enough to actually fire up Reflector) that this is pretty much the same thing that `ComponentModel.Container` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

For who cares, I just added a "DisposeIfNotNull" method. Writing my own IContainer seems overkill, since I'll then too will have to manually add the objects to the container ...

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthLineBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthLineBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthHeaderLineBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(shadowBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthHeaderLineBrushDark);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthFontBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(weekendBgBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(whiteBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(dayFontBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(chartBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(chartWarningBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(barBrush);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthLinePen);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthHeaderLinePen);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthHeaderLinePenDark);
            DisposeIfNotNull(warningLinePen);
            DisposeIfNotNull(monthFont);
            DisposeIfNotNull(yearFont);
            DisposeIfNotNull(weekLinePen);
            DisposeIfNotNull(dayLinePen);
            DisposeIfNotNull(tooltip);
            DisposeIfNotNull(toolTipLabel);
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void DisposeIfNotNull(IDisposable objToDispose)
    {
        if (objToDispose != null)
            objToDispose.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I agree that a custom container is probably overkill for you. The real question is probably why are you keeping around all of those brushes and pens in memory? Creating and disposing of them on the fly is cheap enough to just do in your `Paint` event handler. You really aren't saving much by creating them once and trying to cache.

Comment: Yes you are 100% right. I will update the code. Thanks for all the help! :-)